# Problem to define the data model with Text.Json and source generator

Tags: c#, sourcegenerators

I would like to use Text.Json with source generator.

Given the following json string:

```
var json = @"[[{""OU2CJ3-UBRYG-KCPVS5"":{""cost"":""27187.08000"",""vol_exec"":""3.40000000"",""fee"":""27.18708"",""avg_price"":""7996.20000""}}]]";
```

I tried with the following data model and several flavors, but it seems incorrect as the deserialize output lead to null data. I don't see how to handle the double array definition in this scenario.

```
[JsonSerializable(typeof(OpenOrder), GenerationMode = JsonSourceGenerationMode.Default)]
public partial class MyContext: JsonSerializerContext
{
}   

public partial class OpenOrder
{
    public  Dictionary<string, OpenOrderFrame>  OrderFrame { get; set; }
}

public partial class OpenOrderFrame
{
    public string fee { get; set; }

    public string cost { get; set; }

    public string vol_exec { get; set; }

    public string avg_price { get; set; }
} 

var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, MyContext.Default.OpenOrder);
```

No exception is thrown but result contains null data.
What is the correct model  definition that match the input json string ?

Comment: Who gives you that JSON and do you have the opportunity to slap them around a bit with a large trout? But you probably need `typeof(OpenOrder[][])` or `typeof(OpenOrder[,])`.

Comment: Unfortunatly no, I can't ask them to make the format more standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type structure does not represent the json correctly, you need `Dictionary<string, Tests.OpenOrderFrame>` in double nested collection (though do not know why the code have not produced any errors for you - for me it did). For example next worked for me:

```cs
[JsonSerializable(typeof(Dictionary<string, OpenOrderFrame>[][]), GenerationMode = JsonSourceGenerationMode.Default)]
public partial class MyContext: JsonSerializerContext
{
}

var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, MyContext.Default.DictionaryStringOpenOrderFrameArrayArray);
```

Comment: I have a more complicated json: **@"[[{""OU2CJ3-UBRYG-KCPVS5"":{""cost"":""27187.08000"",""vol_exec"":""3.40000000"",""fee"":""27.18708"",""avg_price"":""7996.20000""}}],""openOrders"",{""sequence"": 59342}]""**.

Comment: How do you modify `Dictionary<string, OpenOrderFrame>[][]` to handle the fact that the first array as a Jarray: **[{""OU2CJ3-UBRYG-KCPVS5"":{""cost"":""27187.08000"",""vol_exec"":""3.40000000"",""fee"":""27.18708"",""avg_price"":""7996.20000""}}]**, a string: **""openOrders""** and JObject: **{""sequence"": 59342}**

Comment: I have tried this for instance without sucess : `typeof(List<(Dictionary<string, OpenOrder>[], string)>)`

Comment: @GuillaumeParis I recommend to use some tools that allow to generate class structure from json. For example https://app.quicktype.io/ or https://json2csharp.com/

Comment: I will open a new question, I would like to use source generator and I need to have the correct syntax which is a little bit tricky in my last scenario, thanks a lot for you help